# Gnuplot pm3d plots "inf" value white

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using these options to plot my 3D map of energy surface.

```
set cbrange [-60:60]
 
set palette maxcolors 13 model RGB defined (0 "#0ab3f7",1 "#4dabec",2 "#6da2df", 3 "#8599d3", 4 "#9a8fc5",5 "#ac84b6", 6 "#bc79a7", 7 "#cc6c95", 8 "#da5d81",9 "#e74c69", 10 "#f3364a", 11 "#f4344
7", 12 "#ff0000") 

set cbtics ("-50" -50, "-40" -40, "-30" -30 , "-20" -20, "-10" -10, "0" 0, "10" 10, "20" 20, "30" 30, "40" 40, "50" 50, "inf" 60)
```

But can't give inf values any color. How can i do that ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please show a few lines of example data? Do you have `inf` and `-inf` and/or `NaN` and `-NaN`. These values can/will not be plotted. So, which color should an unplotted datapoint have? Default is background, so apparently white. What color would you like it to have?

Comment: @theozh

0.000000 0.000000 inf 0.000000 0.000000

 0.012566 0.000000 inf 0.000000 0.000000

 0.025133 0.000000 inf 0.000000 0.000000

 0.037699 0.000000 inf 0.000000 0.000000

 0.050265 0.000000 inf 0.000000 0.000000

 0.062832 0.000000 inf 0.000000 0.000000

 0.075398 0.000000 inf 0.000000 0.000000

 0.087965 0.000000 inf 0.000000 0.000000

 0.100531 0.000000 inf 0.000000 0.000000

 0.113097 0.000000 inf 0.000000 0.000000

Comment: Again, what color would you like `inf` to have?

Answer (score 1):

This should happen automatically if your data actually contains Inf or -Inf.  Here is the first plot from the online demo collection [imageNaN.dem](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/imageNaN.html).

```
# This is the first plot from "imageNaN.dem" in the gnuplot demo set
#
set title "Treatment of missing/undefined/NaN/Inf data"
unset key
set tic scale 0
set border 3 front

set cbrange [-2:7]
set cblabel "Score"
set cbtics 0,1,5

set xrange [-0.5:4.5]
set yrange [-0.5:5.5]

set datafile missing "?"
set ytics ("-Inf" 5, "Inf" 4, "NaN" 3, "Junk" 2, "?" 1, "0" 0)
unset xtics

# Define the test data as a named data block
$matrixdata << EOD
0    5 4 3  0
?    2 2 0  1
Junk 1 2 3  5
NaN  0 0 3  0
Inf  3 2 0  3
-Inf 0 1 2  3
EOD

set view map
plot $matrixdata matrix with image
```

[image]